# Redis is empty after startup, altough there is an .rdb file

Tags: redis, startup

After I ran "shutdown save" in my redis-cli, waited for the "save" command to finish (followed the redis log) and backed up my redis .rdb file, I tried starting the redis server from the begining and it was started with an empty DB (dbsize =0!!!).

What can I do ? How can I restore my redis from the .rdb file?

Comment: Is .rdb file empty? Anything  in redis logs?

Comment: rdb is ~11GB - don't think it's empty..

Comment: What about the logs?

Comment: Is it configured for AOF, so nothing is loaded because it expects an AOF? Just edit the config and comment "appendonly yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed in my configuration file. I saved my `.rdb` file called `tal.rdb` as `old-tal.rdb` so it won't be effected. 
Then, I've started my Redis server again, saw it has 0 keys, inserted `10000` keys and ran the `save"`command and, as a result, I saw it has created a file `dump.rdb` (the default `dbfilename` for Redis `.rdb files`) in the correct directory path, although in the configuration file the `dbfilename` was `tal.rdb`, so I understand my configuration file was bad. To fix this, I replaced the configuration file with a backed up file and restarted my Redis with a copy of `tal.rdb` and then it was started correctly (10M keys). 
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend checking the following things:

1. In your configuration file, check to see that the `dir` and `dbfilename` properties reflect the disk location and filename at which you would expect to find the `.rdb` file (and of course verify that the correct `.rdb` file is at the expected path).
2. In your server logs, when starting up the Redis service, see if you see a log message similar to `DB loaded from disk: x.xxx seconds` appearing.  If the message doesn't appear, or if the message appears with something very close to `0.000 seconds` (which is probably not a reasonable expectation runtime for loading an 11 GB `.rdb` file from disk), then that may be another hint that your configuration isn't looking for the `.rdb` file in the right place.

Comment: The problem was indeed in my configuration file. I saved my rdb "tal.rdb" as "old-tal.rdb" so it won't be effected and then I've started my redis server again, saw it has 0 keys, inserted 10000 keys and ran the "save" command, then I saw it has created a file "dump.rdb" in the correct directory path, altough in the conf file the dbfilename was "tal.rdb", so I understand my conf file was bad, so I replaced it with a backuped conf file and re-started my redis with a copy of "tal.rdb" and then it was started correctly (10M keys).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem.
 "Db loaded in 0.000 second " .and Key * shows empty list.

For resolving this issue

1. Created a backup of dump.rdb file.
2. Stop the server.
3. Removed the dump.rdb file from redis/dump.rdb .
4. Copy the backup to the redis folder

   sudo cp dump.rdb /etc/redis/dump.rdb
5. Restart the server

   127.0.0.1:6379>KEYS *

It Works.

Comment: It am on ubuntu 14.04. I will check and reply. thank

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in server migration. I checked `dir` and `dbfilename` directives in redis.conf too many times but it didn't load the keys. To my experience, in server migration this steps should be passed in order:

1. Dump keys in source server (use save command)
2. Dump keys in destination server
3. Exchange *.rdb file in destination server with the one exported in source server.
4. Reset redis service in destination.

Don't forget step 2.

CAUTION: Step 3 will remove your keys in destination server, these steps are just for server migration.

Don't forget to check `dbfilename` and `dir` directives in redis.conf.